# Show/hide div on link click

Tags: jquery, html, click, hide, show

hey i got projects in a row and when i click on them or hover i want another div to show up beloew,

i have this for html.

```
<div id="projectspace">
   <div class="project">
        <a href="#" class="showdiv"><img src="images/gird systems.png" width="160px" /></a>
        <a class="viewbutton" href="pdf/grid systems.pdf">View</a>
   </div>

   <div class="project">
       <a href="#" class="showdiv"><img src="images/peace one day.jpg" width="160ppx" /></a>
       <a class="viewbutton" href="images/peace one day.jpg">View</a>
   </div>

   <div class="project">
       <a href="#" class="showdiv"><img src="images/dan_test.jpg" width="160ppx" /></a>
       <a class="viewbutton" href="images/dan_test.jpg">View</a>
   </div>
</div>

<div  class="hoverdiv">
    <div id="info">
        <p> some text.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
       <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this for query

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Query(".showdiv").click(function() {
        jQuery(".hoverdiv").find(".description", this).toggle();

        return false;   
     });
});
```

anyone got a better solution?

thanks

Comment: Is there a problem with what you have now? Does it not work?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not problem description. File an [edit] with the exact details of "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this for hover:

```
var hoverDivDescription = $(".hoverdiv").find(".description");

$(".showdiv").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(ev) {
  if (ev.type == "moouseenter") {
    hoverDivDescription.show();
  } else {
    hoverDivDescription.hide();
  }
});
```

Or for click:

```
var hoverDivDescription = $(".hoverdiv").find(".description");

jQuery(function($) {
  $(".showdiv").on("click", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    hoverDivDescription.toggle();
  });
});
```

See this codepen for an example of click (clicking on the images works): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgNWNR?editors=101

Comment: worked! thanks, except i can't change the description for other projects only goes for one project

Comment: That would depend on markup, if you post the multi project markup (use codepen if possible), I can help you out. But for the most part you can just create a function and search by context.

Comment: on mark up, could i do a < div class"discrioton" and inside that do a div with id discitions named the ids the title of the discrioption? i could try that on code pen

Comment: You can try something like the following http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbLGGG. Basically, you can use data attributes to target your projects. Clicking on each image should toggle different sections based on the data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this;

```
$(".showdiv").mousedown(function(){
    $("div to show").show()
});

$(".showdiv").mouseup(function(){
    $("div to hide").hide()
});
```

Comment: tried it, doesn't seem to make a difference, is there anything that needs to be done with the css? so far i haven't changed anything, but the description and info are always visible when they should be hided until clicked i guess

Comment: The css of the "div to show" should be; display: none;